# Выделение контуров и вложенных контуров на основе 4-связности (соседство по вертикали и горизонтали)

Tags: python, алгоритм, изображения, opencv, матрицы

Для моей задачи очень важно чтобы контуры выделялись на основе 4-связности и соседи по диагонали не учитывались (как на рисунке тут)

[image: такие соседи должны различаться как разные контуры]

также важно различать контуры по иерархии (отдельно содержать внешние и отдельно внутренние контуры), однако функция `findContours()` из OpenCV использует 8-связность для получения контуров.

Я также знаю что в библиотеке OpenCV есть функция `connectedComponents()` которая находит связные компоненты и может учитывать связность, которую мы ей передадим, но не понимаю как ее можно применить для нахождения контуров на изображении.

я попытался реализовать алгоритм Сузуки 85 для выделения связных пикселей и он распознает контуры на основе 4-связности, однако только внешние, не совсем понимаю как проверять что контур находится именно внутри другого контура.

Пожалуйста помогите мне понять что я должен использовать для такого выделения контуров. Можно ли настроить OpenCV на выделение контуров на основе 4-связности? Если нет посоветуйте как мне проверять что контур находится внутри другого контура.

Вот алгоритм выделения контура написанный на Python:

````
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Создаем двоичное изображение (0 - фон, 1 - объект)
binary_image = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],], dtype=np.uint8)

def suzuki85_no_diagonals(binary_image):
    label = 1
    labels = np.zeros_like(binary_image, dtype=np.uint16)

    def neighbor_labels(y, x):
        neighbors = []
        for dx in [-1, 1]:
            if 0 <= x + dx < binary_image.shape[2]:
                neighbor_label = labels[y, x + dx]
                if neighbor_label > 0:
                    neighbors.append(neighbor_label)
        for dy in [-1, 1]:
            if 0 <= y + dy < binary_image.shape[0]:
                neighbor_label = labels[y + dy, x]
                if neighbor_label > 0:
                    neighbors.append(neighbor_label)
        return neighbors

    for y in range(binary_image.shape[0]):
        for x in range(binary_image.shape[2]):
            if binary_image[y, x] == 1:
                neighbor = neighbor_labels(y, x)
                if not neighbor:
                    labels[y, x] = label
                    label += 1
                else:
                    min_neighbor = min(neighbor)
                    labels[y, x] = min_neighbor
                    for neighbor_label in neighbor:
                        if neighbor_label != min_neighbor:
                            labels[labels == neighbor_label] = min_neighbor

    return labels

# Найдем контуры без учета соседства по диагонали
labels = suzuki85_no_diagonals(binary_image)
#print(labels)
# Функция для поиска внешних и внутренних контуров
def find_outer_inner_contours(labels):
    outer_contours = []
    inner_contours = []
    unique_labels = np.unique(labels)
    
    unique_labels = unique_labels[1:]  # Исключаем фон
    #print(unique_labels)
    for label in unique_labels:
        # Извлекаем координаты пикселей с этой меткой
        points = np.argwhere(labels == label)
        #print(label)
        # Проверяем, является ли контур внешним (имеет хотя бы одного соседа с другой меткой)
        is_outer = False
        for point in points:
            y, x = point
            #print(y, " ", x)



            for dx in [-1, 1]:
                if x + dx < labels.shape[2] and labels[y, x + dx] != label and labels[y, x - dx] != label:
                    is_outer = True
                    break
            for dy in [-1, 1]:
                if y + dy < labels.shape[0] and labels[y + dy, x] != label and labels[y - dy, x] != label:
                    is_outer = True
                    break

        if is_outer == True:
            outer_contours.append(points)
        else:
            inner_contours.append(points)

    return outer_contours, inner_contours

# Найдем внешние и внутренние контуры
outer_contours, inner_contours = find_outer_inner_contours(labels)

# Выведем результат (каждый контур представлен списком точек)
print("Количество внешних контуров:", len(outer_contours))
print("Количество внутренних контуров:", len(inner_contours))```
````

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример для "контур находится именно внутри другого контура".